# How to pass multiple objects with same name to SOAP?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I've found several answers that work for scalars but not for nested objects. To make it simple, this is a simplified XML of what I should produce:

```
<order>
    <date>2019-08-28</date>
    <orderLines>
        <orderLine>
            <productCode>123</productCode>
            <quantity>12</quantity>
            <unitPrice>99.66</unitPrice>
        </orderLine>
        <orderLine>
            <productCode>987</productCode>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <unitPrice>4500.00</unitPrice>
        </orderLine>
    </orderLines>
</order>
```

The factory method to create an object does something like this:

```
$order = new \stdClass();
$order->date = "2019-08-27"

$orderItems = [];
foreach($orderManager->getOrderItems() as $orderCartItem){
    $orderItem = new \stdClass();
    $orderItem->productCode = $orderCartItem->getProdCode();
    $orderItem->quantity = $orderCartItem->getQty();
    $orderItem->unitPrice = $orderCartItem->getUnitPrice();
    $orderItems[] = $orderItem;
}

$order->orderLines = $orderItems;
```

This is obviously won't work because I cannot determine what is the name of the orderItem XML elements.

How could I represent this XML structure in an object?